# Como acrescentar a palavra "anos" apos calcular a idade

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
document.getElementById("data").addEventListener('change', function() {
  var data = new Date(this.value);
  if (isDate_(this.value) && data.getFullYear() > 1900)
    document.getElementById("idade").value = calculateAge(this.value);
});

function calculateAge(dobString) {
  var dob = new Date(dobString);
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
  var birthdayThisYear = new Date(currentYear, dob.getMonth(), dob.getDate());
  var age = currentYear - dob.getFullYear();
  if (birthdayThisYear > currentDate) {
    age--;
  }
  return age;
}

function calcular(data) {
  var data = document.form.nascimento.value;
  alert(data);
  var partes = data.split("/");
  var junta = partes[2] + "-" + partes[1] + "-" + partes[0];
  document.form.idade.value = (calculateAge(junta));
}

var isDate_ = function(input) {
  var status = false;
  if (!input || input.length <= 0) {
    status = false;
  } else {
    var result = new Date(input);
    if (result == 'Invalid Date') {
      status = false;
    } else {
      status = true;
    }
  }
  return status;
}
```

```css
h3 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

.form-group label {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 0;
  color: #333;
}

.form-group input {
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,300,400,500,600,700|Playfair+Display:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

<h3>Informações Pessoais</h3>

<hr>

<form>

  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" class="form-control text-uppercase" placeholder="Digite seu nome">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label for="data">Data de Nascimento:</label>
    <input type="date" name="data" id="data" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-1">
    <label for="idade">Idade:</label>
    <input type="num" name="idade" id="idade" class="form-control" placeholder="Idade" disabled>
  </div>

</form>
```

Ele me retorna a idade do jeito que eu quero, só que eu não sei como que eu faço para retornar o `anos`  logo após a idade.

O código já ta pronto, todo montado, só é preciso implementar o nome logo após a idade, e eu não sei como fazer isso, se alguém puder ler o código e me explicar, eu agradeço.

Comment: Na `function calculateAge`, acrescente no retorno: `return age+" anos";`

Comment: É ISSO AÍ MESMO! VALEU AMIGO!

Answer (score 1):

seria isso que precisa

```js
document.getElementById("data").addEventListener('change', function() {
  var data = new Date(this.value);
  if (isDate_(this.value) && data.getFullYear() > 1900)
    document.getElementById("idade").value = calculateAge(this.value) + " anos";
});

function calculateAge(dobString) {
  var dob = new Date(dobString);
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
  var birthdayThisYear = new Date(currentYear, dob.getMonth(), dob.getDate());
  var age = currentYear - dob.getFullYear();
  if (birthdayThisYear > currentDate) {
    age--;
  }
  return age;
}

function calcular(data) {
  var data = document.form.nascimento.value;
  alert(data);
  var partes = data.split("/");
  var junta = partes[2] + "-" + partes[1] + "-" + partes[0];
  document.form.idade.value = (calculateAge(junta));
}

var isDate_ = function(input) {
  var status = false;
  if (!input || input.length <= 0) {
    status = false;
  } else {
    var result = new Date(input);
    if (result == 'Invalid Date') {
      status = false;
    } else {
      status = true;
    }
  }
  return status;
}
```

```css
h3 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

.form-group label {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 0;
  color: #333;
}

.form-group input {
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,300,400,500,600,700|Playfair+Display:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

<h3>Informações Pessoais</h3>

<hr>

<form>

  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" class="form-control text-uppercase" placeholder="Digite seu nome">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label for="data">Data de Nascimento:</label>
    <input type="date" name="data" id="data" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-1">
    <label for="idade">Idade:</label>
    <input type="num" name="idade" id="idade" class="form-control" placeholder="Idade" disabled>
  </div>

</form>
```

se for isso basta alterar essa linha

```
document.getElementById("idade").value = calculateAge(this.value);
```

por essa

```
document.getElementById("idade").value = calculateAge(this.value) + " anos";
```

Comment: É ISSO AÍ MESMO! VALEU MUITO OBRIGADO. JÁ ME POUPOU O TRABALHO DE PROCURAR A LINHA HAHAHA